# Bootstap Carousel button not working in atom

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

Im working on carousel but buttons are not working and it has border. Tried to remove border with css but this time buttons also dissappered.

buttons are working on codeply: [bootstrap carousel buttons](https://www.codeply.com/p/iBYRIyg7qb)

```css
/* html tags */
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 900;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.testimonial-image {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}
/* Testimonials Sections */
#testimonials {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  rel="stylesheet">
   <!--Font Awesome-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c02f86903.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" class="testimonial-image" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img src="images/lady-img.jpg" class="testimonial-image" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

is it necessary to add some extras in head section?
I cant figure out the solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the imports of Bootstrap. You have included Bootstrap version `4.3.1`, but used the html syntax for Bootstrap `5+`. You also included the js twice.

Corrected code (including your custom CSS):

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 900;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.testimonial-image {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

/* Testimonials Sections */
#testimonials {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="testimonials">
      <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color:blue;">
            <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
            <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" class="testimonial-image" alt="dog-profile">
            <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color:red;">
            <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
            <img src="images/lady-img.jpg" class="testimonial-image" alt="lady-profile">
            <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'd need to add your stylesheet here, otherwise this should work fine.

Comment: thanks, I tried     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 instead of your correction >>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css"> both of them working, wondering why and whats the difference?

Comment: `JQuery` is a JS library, and `normalize` is a completely different thing to manage your CSS styles cross browsers. They have nothing to do with Bootstrap. It'll work if you remove both, or add both. Older Bootstrap versions (less than 5) needed JQuery to run, but not needed starting version 5.